# Was biblical Shmita observed during the time of the second temple?

Tags: history, shmita

Was biblical shmita observed during the second beit hamikdash? Is there a source for this?

Comment: You mean like a historical source (dug up records, etc.)?

Comment: Yovel certainly wasnt like it is not kept today either.

Answer (score 6):

[I Maccabees 6:49-53](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Maccabees%206&version=NRSV) talks about a siege in which the Jews were short of food because of shmita.

Comment: Was that biblical or rabbinic _shmita_?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, society in general kept *sh'mita* (toward the end of the period of second *bes hamikdash*) to the extent that lenders found themselves unable to collect on loans after *sh'mita* had passed. (That's why they stopped lending — though arguably that can be called **not** keeping *sh'mita* — which is why [the *p'rozbul*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prozbul) was invented.)

Comment: Was that biblical or rabbinic _shmita_?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Torah says not to collect loans after _sh'mita_. I'm unable at the moment to cite _Chinuch_ (or _Chumash_) to that effect. If you can improve the post by doing so, I'd much appreciate it. (And if the downvoter has a suggestion for improvement, I'd love to know it, too.)

Comment: "The Torah says not to collect loans after sh'mita." I'm not aware how that helps clarify if the shmitta being practiced when the prozbul was invented was biblical or rabbinic in nature. Indeed, the link in your answer suggests that the prozbul enactment was actually specifically for rabbinic shmitta times.

Answer (score 1):

See the כסף משנה  says on the Rambam in [הלכות שמיטה ויובל - פרק רביעי](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02022.html#HtmpReportNum0075_L2).

The Rambam says:

> **כה:** אֵין שְׁבִיעִית נוֹהֶגֶת אֶלָּא בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּלְבַד שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ויקרא כה-ב) 'כִּי תָבֹאוּ אֶל הָאָרֶץ' וְגוֹ'. וְנוֹהֶגֶת בֵּין בִּפְנֵי הַבַּיִת בֵּין שֶׁלֹּא בִּפְנֵי הַבַּיִת‏

Making it seems that Shmita is always Biblical.

The  כסף משנה   brings **various sources that already during the 2nd temple period it was Rabbinical**, only. However, he seems to conclude that the **Rambam holds it was Biblical**; leaving us with no definitive conclusion.

> **כסף משנה**  ***אין שביעית נוהגת אלא בא''י בלבד וכו'***. ירושלמי פ''ו דשביעית (הלכה א') ומשנה בספ''ק דקידושין (דף ל"ו:) כל מצוה שהיא תלויה בארץ אינה נוהגת אלא בארץ: ***ונוהגת בין בפני הבית וכו'***. בפרק השולח (גיטין דף ל"ו) לגבי פרוזבול רבי היא דתניא וזה דבר השמטה שמוט בשתי שמטות הכתוב מדבר אחת שמטת קרקע ואחת שמטת כספים בזמן שאתה משמט קרקע אתה משמט כספים ובזמן שאי אתה משמט קרקע אי אתה משמט כספים ופירש רש''י אע''ג דהלל בבית שני הוה ס''ל לאביי **דבבית שני הואיל ולא היה היובל נוהג לא נהגו שמיטין מדאורייתא** ודאמרי' בערכין מנו יובלות לקדש שמיטין **מדרבנן קאמר** (ומצאתי בתלמידי רבינו יצחק הלוי שכתב במס' גיטין) בירושלמי מניין **שאין השמטה נוהגת אלא בזמן שהיובל נוהג** שנאמר וזה דבר השמטה שמוט אחת שמטת יובל ואחת שמטת שביעית אבל בת''כ ראיתי דשביעית נוהגת בזמן שאין יובל נוהג ואומר אני שהוא מחלוקת עכ''ל. ומדברי רבינו פה נראה שהוא סובר דאף שלא בפני הבית נוהגת מן התורה ופסק כההיא דת''כ משום דמשמע דההיא כחכמים דפליגי עליה דרבי והלכה כרבים אבל קשה שהרי כתב בפרק ט' ההיא דקתני רבי בזמן שאתה משמט קרקע אתה משמט כספים ועוד דההיא דפרוזבול ליתא אלא  אליבא דרבי וכיון שרבינו פסקה לההיא דפרוזבול משמע דסבר לה כרבי והיאך נאמר שכאן פסק כחכמים ? לפיכך נ''ל דלעולם כרבי ס''ל ול''ק שהוא ז''ל מפרש הא דאמר רבי בשתי שמטות הכתוב מדבר אחת שמטת קרקעות לא אשמטת קרקעות בשביעית קאמר דההיא לעולם נהגה אף שלא בפני הבית אלא ליובל קרי שמטת קרקעות שהרי השדות חוזרות לבעלים וכמבואר בדבריו רפ''ט וכן פירש ר''ת אבל קשה שכתב רבינו בפירוש בזמן שאין היובל נוהג אינו נוהג אחת מכל אלו חוץ משביעית בארץ והשמטת כספים בכל מקום מדבריהם הרי שכתב בשביעית בזמן שאין היובל נוהג אינה אלא מדבריהם ואפילו שביעית דקרקעות וי''ל דמדבריהם דקאמר לא קאי אלא להשמטת כספים דסמיך ליה דאילו שמטת קרקעות מדאורייתא נמי נהגה בכל זמן ואי הוה אמרינן שמה שכתב רבינו כאן דנוהגת אף שלא בפני הבית מדרבנן הוה ניחא אבל פשטא דמילתא דמדאורייתא קאמר: ‏

Comment: See Rambam 10:10, 12 as quoted below from an similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate answer is also found here as posted by @DoubleAA. I am not sure if this is a duplicate or not.

[Why is Shmita only Rabbinic nowadays?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/why-is-shmita-only-rabbinic-nowadays)

> Rambam Shemitta veYovel 10:10,12
>
> משגלה שבט ראובן ושבט גד וחצי שבט מנשה, בטלו היובלות--שנאמר "וקראתם דרור בארץ, לכל יושביה", בזמן שכל יושביה עליה: והוא שלא יהיו מעורבין
>   שבט בשבט, אלא כולן יושבים כתקנן.‏
>       ...
>       ובזמן שאין היובל נוהג, אין נוהג עבד עברי, ולא בתי ערי חומה, ולא שדה אחוזה, ולא שדה חרמים, ואין מקבלין גר תושב; ונוהגת שביעית בארץ
>   מדבריהם, וכן השמטת כספים בכל מקום מדבריהם כמו שביארנו.‏
>
> Once the tribe of Reuben and the tribe of Gad and half the tribe of Menashe were exiled, the Jubilee ended, as it says "and proclaim
>   liberty throughout the land unto all the inhabitants thereof" when all
>   its inhabitants are on it, and they cannot be mixed up tribes with
>   tribes, rather each sitting as appointed [in their tribal plots].
>
> ...
>
> And when the Jubilee is not practiced, neither is [the laws of] the Jewish slave, nor the houses of the walled cities, nor the
>   inherited land, nor the consecrated land, nor do we accept Gerei
>   Toshav. And Shemitta is in force in Israel by rabbinic decree as is
>   the nullification of loans in all places by rabbinic decree as we
>   explained. (my translation)
>
> Essentially, Shemitta doesn't apply when Yovel doesn't, and Yovel
>   doesn't unless the Jews live in Israel by tribe. shareeditflag
>
> answered Sep 21 '14 at 6:16 Double AA♦
>   51.9k5115229
>
> Is his opinion pretty representative of the general consensus? –  Robert S. Barnes Sep 21 '14 at 8:48 1
>
> @RobertS.Barnes No. See the Kesef Mishna to the beginning of chapter 9, for example. But it is the more commonly accepted opinion –
>   Matt Sep 21 '14 at 17:11